# Initializing an array using a method - Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have a text file with n amount of athletes names, each name on a new line, and the number of athletes is written as an int on the first line of the text file. The code i have written so far reads the text file, and using scanner and creates  an array with all the data (Athletes names).
What I wondering is, is it possible to use a method to create a separate array for each athlete (I will later fill these with data on scores/ performance). I cannot initialize these before the text file is scanned as the number of athletes will not yet be known.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TextScanner {

  private static void readFile(String fileName) {
    try {
      List<String> distance = new ArrayList<String>();
      File file = new File(fileName);
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
      while (scanner.hasNext()) {
          distance.add(scanner.next());
      }
      scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    readFile(args[0]);
  }
}
```

Very new to Java, so I apologise. I have looked around and cant seem to find any information.
Thanks

Comment: may this help you ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777274/dynamic-arraylist-in-java

Comment: You can create a new type/class to represent your Athlete info and add to list or a Map... so later you can again set properties of those objects as required..

Comment: then you can use HashMap<String,List> and arraylist is dynamic.

Comment: @newuserua_ext Thanks, yeh i saw that, but i think most of the answers misunderstood his question, and were focusing on adding elements to an existing array.

Comment: No Most of users doesn't misunderstood , they are trying to tell you the Correct way of doing it ! `Everytime the way which solves your problem is not the correct and only way!`

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible , but `Array` has certain limitation as it can not expand and collapse dynamically

Try this way

Create a Class `Athelete`  having attributes you want to keep for athelete

Say

```
Class Athelete{

private String name;
private Integer age;
private String skill;

// then Getters and Setters for each of these
}
```

and create a Map

```
Map<String,Athelete> // having `name` as Key and `athelete object` as value.
```

Now Read from file and create Athelete Object and add it to `Map`.

```
Person p=new Person();
p.setName=nameFromFile();
// also set further attributes
map.put(p.getName,p);
```

Comment: @XavierDSouza Should have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can create class `Athlete`:

```
class Athlete{
   String name;
   int score;
   Athlete(String name){
      this.name = name;
   }
   int getScore(){return score;}
   void setScore(int score){ this.score = score}
}
```

and insert instances of `Athlete` into array or List:

```
List<Athlete> distance = new ArrayList<>();
distance.add(new Athlete('Some name'));
```

UPD: if you use Java7 consider `java.nio.file.Files` instead `Scanner` for read **small** files. I think [readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) method will useful for you.

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify, if i were to run a for loop, or something similar, i could continually create new objects for each athlete using the class? Appreciate your help

Comment: @user3636636 Create new instance in loop it usual OOP (and java as OOP language) pattern. You can find it in either book about java.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java is object oriented language think objects and in your case its seems to be Athlete, Score and Performance

```
public class Athlete {
    String name;
    List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();
    List<Performance> performances = new ArrayList<Performance>();
}

public class Score {
    String score
}

public class Performance {
    int performnce
}
```

So `List<String> distance = new ArrayList<String>();` this will become `List<Athlete> Athletes = new ArrayList<Athlete>();`

For each record in the file create Athlete object and store the name in `name` instance variable. As you get the scores and performances for each particular Athlete updte the Athlete objects already created above.

**Update**

As other commentator have pointed out using a `Map` rather than `List`would be suitable.
for eg `Map<String, Athlete> athletes = new HashMap<String, Athlete>();` 
This way updating later on receiveing the score s and performances becomes easier.
Also, scores and performances are List as an Athlete could have multiple score and performnces.

Answer (score 0):

you can first add all the data (Athletes names) to a list and later call list.toArray(new Athlete[list.size()]); this will get you your required Array

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can create an array for each record from the file. The method signature would look like e.g.

```
String[] readAthleteData() {...}
```

However, using collections like ArrayList is usually more convenient than arrays.